# XSLT - Attribute changing (regular expression?)

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to update a XML file (generated by WiX).  I have it working almost perfectly.  But, I have found an internal reference I also need to replace, and it is a bit more complicated.

In a nutshell, I am appending _32x to the value of Id in several XML nodes.  But, I have found a reference within the XML to the Id, which also must be appended.

That is, the original XML file (greatly simplified and with other attributes removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="WEBINSTALLFOLDER">
      <Directory Id="dir1DB31186637C634CBA8E0643DF80869C">
        <Component Id="cmp65024F0DF585708F9ABEBE2F58FF64BA">
          <File Id="fil8C400D2459FD744947D08FD584B820E4" />
          <RegistryValue Value="ASP.dashboard_aspx" />
          <RegistryValue Value="App_Web_10b5qifx" />
          <RegistryValue Value="v4.0.30319" />
          <RegistryValue Value="file:///[#fil8C400D2459FD744947D08FD584B820E4]" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

My XSLT appends _32x to the Id values in the Component and Files correctly (and adds a reference to Definitions.wxi).  All of that is working perfectly, but I must also change any RegistryValue node with a Value of 'file:///[#...' with a new value that replaces ']' with '_32x]'.

That is, the new tag should be:

```
<RegistryValue Value="file:///[#fil8C400D2459FD744947D08FD584B820E4_32x]" />
```

My current XSLT is:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/> 
<xsl:template match="wix:Wix"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:processing-instruction name="include">..\Definitions.wxi</xsl:processing-instruction> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/> 
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template> 
<!-- Identity transform. --> 
<xsl:template match="@*|node()"> 
    <xsl:copy> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> 
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>  
<xsl:template match="@Id[parent::wix:Component]">
  <xsl:attribute name="Id">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>_32x</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@Id[parent::wix:File]">
  <xsl:attribute name="Id">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>_32x</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

And the final XML RIGHT NOW, without the correction on the RegistryValue is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<?include ..\Definitions.wxi?>
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="WEBINSTALLFOLDER">
      <Directory Id="dir1DB31186637C634CBA8E0643DF80869C">
        <Component Id="cmp65024F0DF585708F9ABEBE2F58FF64BA_32x">
          <File Id="fil8C400D2459FD744947D08FD584B820E4_32x" />
          <RegistryValue Value="ASP.dashboard_aspx" />
          <RegistryValue Value="App_Web_10b5qifx" />
          <RegistryValue Value="v4.0.30319" />
          <RegistryValue Value="file:///[#fil8C400D2459FD744947D08FD584B820E4]" />
        </Component>
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

I am pretty new to XSLT, so, not sure how to do the replacement on the RegistryValue node's Value, when specifically that file:///[#.. and do the replacement.

This happens over and over in my XML file, with different actual file id's, so a simple hard-coded constant replacement is not possible.

Thank you

Comment: You haven't mentioned whether you are able to use XSLT 2.0, which makes this kind of thing very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must also change any RegistryValue node with a Value of
>   'file:///[#...' with a new value that replaces ']' with '_32x]'.

You can do that even without regular expressions:

```
<xsl:template match="wix:RegistryValue/@Value[starts-with(., 'file:///[#')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(., ']')" />
        <xsl:text>_32x]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would adding this template help:

```
<xsl:template match="@Value[parent::wix:RegistryValue and matches(.,'^file:///\[#.*\]$')]">
    <xsl:attribute name="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,']'), '_32x', ']')"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```